# Django Unit Testing: cannot mock django.core.urlresolvers.resolve

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to mock the *django.core.urlresolvers.resolve* function, but it doesn't seem to be work. I've tested with custom functions and it works like a charm, but mock ignores *resolve* completely.

Code:

**test_something.py:**

```
class SomethingTestCase(TestCase)
    def setUp(self):
        self.middleware = SomeMiddleware()
        self.request = Mock()
        self.request.session = {}

    @patch('django.core.urlresolvers.resolve', side_effect=lambda: None)
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.middleware.process_request(self.request), None)
```

**middleware.py**

```
class SomeMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        app = resolve(request.path).app_name
        print('App name: {}'.format(app))
```

This results in the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_process_request_unauthenticated (something.tests.unit.test_middleware.SomethingTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/virtualenv/something/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/home/user/projects/something/working/something/tests/unit/test_middleware.py", line 23, in test_process_request_unauthenticated
    self.assertEqual(self.middleware.process_request(self.request), None)
  File "/home/user/projects/something/working/something/middleware.py", line 14, in process_request
    app = resolve(request.path).app_name
  File "/home/user/virtualenv/something/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 534, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/home/user/virtualenv/something/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 405, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'path': path})
Resolver404: {u'path': u"<Mock name='mock.path' id='140678271233168'>"}
```

My goal here is to make the *resolve* function returns something where I can get the app name.

Why is mock.patch unable to override the resolve function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are patching it at the wrong location. You should patch it in file it is being used, and not where it is defined as more often than not the target code is imported before the patch is run.

Secondly, if the mocking works it would raise an error something on the lines of `NoneType object has no attribute app_name`.

```
@patch(<path_to_middleware.py>, side_effect=lambda: type('mock', (object,), {'app_name': 1})):
def test_something(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.middleware.process_request(self.request), None)
```

Comment: Oh, that's makes complete sense. Thank you!